# Syntax Error MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, mips

I am trying to make an assembly program and I get the below error.

It is my first time using QTSpim Simulator.

[image: Error Print Screen]

My file start with

```
.data

N: .word 5

X: .word 2,4,6,8,10

SUM: .word 0
```

---

another Syntax Error

[image]

Comment: Looks like a byte order mark. Save your text file with the encoding set to ANSI

Comment: ok what about syntax errors .... i get the same warning but with syntax error ...... what about that

Comment: @harold can you answer me please ? ^_^

Comment: Can you show the error? (btw I was making dinner)

Comment: Is the `:` actually in the file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17654/discussion-between-mahmoud-and-harold)

Comment: Please add an/the answer and accept it, if it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete the program. Try this:

```
.data

N:   .word 5
X:   .word 2,4,6,8,10
SUM: .word 0

     .text
     .globl main

main:

     #your code here

li $v0, 10
syscall
.end
```